# Rails: Devise authenticate with current password before deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Devise gem 3.0.1 in my Rails 4 app.

By default It is possible to delete the user record without authenticate with current password (the current password is only required when I provide a new email or password).

So is there a best practise in Devise available to add an authentication with current password before deleting the user record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you should be adding `before_action :authenicate_user!` to any controllers that require authentication.  This will prevent *any* activity unless the user is logged in.  A common practice is to add this line to the ApplicationController or some abstract controller so that other controllers that require authentication can inherit from it.

For areas of your application that won't require a logged in user to access (such as the login page, landing page, etc), you can either use `skip_before_action` or simply inherit from a different base controller.

Comment: `Rails 4` used `before_action` instead of `before_filter`

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c look at it Thanks

Comment: `before_action :authenicate_user!` is already included in my `application_cintroller.rb`. In addition to that I want that the user hat to enter his current password to ensure that the owner is make this operation. I want prevent the following situation: A user forgot to logout and leave the computer nobody can opens the page and delete the user record.

Comment: @Heiko - Devise doesn't supply you with the UI to do this, but it's fairly simple to make a custom `before_action` method to re-require a password.  An even simpler solution might be to auto-expire the session after a set amount of time - this should be done regardless and may suffice for your case.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the problem by adding a `before_action` which looks for current password on delete action.